# Gradle 'ProjectName' project refresh failed: failed get query package name for debug error in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 0.5.2 and everything was ok 2 hours ago. After reopening the project now it gives the following error.

> Gradle 'ProjectName' project refresh failed: Failed get query package
>   name for debug

How can i solve this error?

Comment: There's probably something messed up with one of your build files. Please add them to your question so we can have a look.

Answer (score 12):

I got this error and found out it was because I had errors in AndroidManifest.xml. Some errant text ended up in the file and created numerous errors. I reverted to a previous known good version and Gradle refreshed without issue.

Comment: worked for me, turned out git decided to dump a load of random text into that file.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems like this a few times. Usually if you close it and reopen it the problems go away.

Comment: this is what i do first at every problem, but this time it didn't solve the problem.